# Не получается отфильтровать данные JSON используя JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Хочу отфильтровать полученный json чтобы в html уходило только имя автора и сама цитата. Сама ошибка в фильтре, но какая я не могу понять.

Код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
    //получаю json
    $.getJSON("http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json", function(json) {
      var html = "";
      //фильтр
      var filtered = json.filter(function(val){
        return val.author && val.quote;
      });
      //перебираю данные и вывожу в html
      $.each(filtered, function(key, val){
        html += "<div class = 'quote'>";
        html += "<p> author: " + key + "</p>" + "<p>" + val + "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
      });
      $('.message').html(html);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Что за метод `filter`? Откуда он взялся? Не могу найти его в документации к jQuery API

Comment: @vihtor, это наводящий вопрос для автора?) Если нет, то это из PureJS - [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @vihtor https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_filter.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере всё просто - возвращается объект с одной цитатой и перебирать его нет необходимости.

```js
$("#get-message").on("click", function(){
    $.getJSON("http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json", function(data) {
      $('#quote p').html('"' + data.quote + '" - ' + data.author);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="get-message">get-message</div>
<div id="message">
    <div id="quote">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Предполагая, что параметр `json` - массив:

```
  var html = "";
  //фильтр
  var filtered = json.map(function(val){
    return { author: val.author, quote: val.quote };
  });
  //перебираю данные и вывожу в html
  $.each(filtered, function(key, val){
    html += "<div class = 'quote'>";
    html += "<p> author: " + val.author + "</p>" + "<p>" + val.quote + "</p>";
    html += "</div>";
  });
  $('.message').html(html);
```

Comment: Как-то это бессмысленно выглядит ... Что мешает по изначальному массиву сразу пройтись `$.each`'ом и вытянуть то что надо? Я понимаю ещё то, что автор вопроса не особо понимает как и что работает, но делать такое в ответе - как-то неправильно.